# style a Rails form_for with radio buttons to Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

This is type of button that interests me:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Radio 1 (preselected)
  </label>
</div>
```

And currently my form in Rails looks like this

```
<%= form_for [current_user, rsvp], remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :event_id %>
    <%= f.radio_button :status, "attending", :onclick => "this.form.submit();" %>
    <%= f.radio_button :status, "interested", :onclick => "this.form.submit();"%>
    <%= f.radio_button :status, "not_interested", :onclick => "this.form.submit();" %>
<% end %>
```

HTML that the form above produces:

```
<form class="edit_rsvp" id="edit_rsvp_10" action="/users/1/rsvps/10" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="MIbWTIdE3/6MJ5ly3oWleBRIvit5WA0CeFm/+caKj049svqPVG8h+uf76NVjxr31d69jlbMWNIIB4Eo7a6R9cw==" />
    <input type="hidden" value="17" name="rsvp[event_id]" id="rsvp_event_id" />
    <input onclick="this.form.submit();" type="radio" value="attending" name="rsvp[status]" id="rsvp_status_attending" />
    <input onclick="this.form.submit();" type="radio" value="interested" checked="checked" name="rsvp[status]" id="rsvp_status_interested" />
    <input onclick="this.form.submit();" type="radio" value="not_interested" name="rsvp[status]" id="rsvp_status_not_interested" />
</form>
```

Sticking the btn class at the end like this `<%= f.radio_button :status, "attending", :onclick => "this.form.submit();", :class => "btn btn-primary" %>`, produces what looks like a standard Rails radio button.

Doing it the other way around produces Bootstrap buttons that don't change anything when you click them

```
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input onclick="this.form.submit();" type="radio" value="attending" name="rsvp[status]" id="rsvp_status_attending" autocomplete="off"> Attending

  </label>
```

**UPDATE 1**
It looks like in Taryn's solution the original Rails radio button just got veiled underneath the new Bootstrap button, a click anywhere on the Bootstrap button produces no controller action. 
[image]

and here's the HTML her code produces:

```
<form class="edit_rsvp" id="edit_rsvp_10" action="/users/1/rsvps/10" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="patch" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="qqtfAy+xZmnklDe+IXVGg2sFbhLC5laWQn4jRBb+RT+nn3PA/JqYbY9IRhmcNl4OCOKzrAiobxY7x9aGu9C3Ag==" />
    <input type="hidden" value="17" name="rsvp[event_id]" id="rsvp_event_id" />
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input onclick="this.form.submit();" type="radio" value="attending" name="rsvp[status]" id="rsvp_status_attending" />
            Attending
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input onclick="this.form.submit();" type="radio" value="interested" checked="checked" name="rsvp[status]" id="rsvp_status_interested" />
            Interested
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input onclick="this.form.submit();" type="radio" value="not_interested" name="rsvp[status]" id="rsvp_status_not_interested" />
            Not Interested
        </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

**UPDATE 2**

trying a `submit` button like so

```
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <%= f.submit :status => "attending", :onclick => "this.form.submit();" %>
        Attending
    </label>
```

still produces overlap and two separate buttons, one from Bootstrap and one from Rails. Only clicking the Rails' grey area triggers the controller action.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a combination of erb and html to make it look like bootstrap.

I haven't tested this, but something like this might work for your buttons:

```
<%= form_for [current_user, rsvp], remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :event_id %>
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">    
    <label class="btn btn-primary active"><%= f.radio_button :status, "attending", :onclick => "this.form.submit();" %></label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary active"><%= f.radio_button :status, "interested", :onclick => "this.form.submit();"%></label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary active"><%= f.radio_button :status, "not_interested", :onclick => "this.form.submit();" %></label>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

You may need to tweak it a bit - I am just combining the two snippets you gave.

Comment: It's not triggering the controller action

Comment: It seems that this way the original radio button just got covered up by the Bootstrap button. See OP for screenshot.

Comment: darn :/ but you've got something pretty that you may now be able to play with. Can you update your question to show us the raw html that gets generated by a) your working code and b) the mashed up version I've got above? it's probably going to be easier for us to make the html functional... then figure out how to implement that in the erb.

Comment: added raw html to OP. Maybe that original JS is interfering, like the `"this.form.submit();"` call?

Comment: Yeah could be... but there shouldn't be any reason why that should happen. Have you checked the js console when you try clicking on those? might be that the button ids get mangled...

Comment: Of course the other thing is... if you have a form.submit - you probably don't need them to be radio-buttons in a form... you could just make them into three ordinary buttons.

Comment: from what I can tell, `button` does not take as many arguments as `radio_button`, though. `button(value = nil, options = {}, &block)`, so would it be something like `f.button "attending", :onclick => "this.form.submit();"`? That can't be right and it doesn't seem like the problem is in the type of button I use, but the fact that Rails and Bootstrap's stuff is physically overlapping each other in the view.

Comment: There is a huge difference between a radio-button and a button... and technically I'm talking about a `button_to` not just `button` - a `button_to` is a separate, individual form that operates like `link_to` - and given that every one of your buttons submits the whole form anyway... Alternatively, you could make these three different variants of `submit` button - and in your controller, just check the value of `submit` to determine the `status`.

Comment: there's still that same overlap, I made an update in OP. unless, my code for f.submit is wrong.

Comment: When they're buttons - they won't have a radio-button to hide... so it's gotta be at least slightly different :)
If the issue is mainly visual (ie overlapping) - do you want to generate the html and maybe put together a jsfiddle for us to muck about with? If it's functional, that will let us figure out how to make it look good. If it's on-functional - that's a different issue to fix...